# Output first, second and third value of selected option in separate divs using selectedIndex value?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to output the first, second and third value of a selected option in separate divs. I have the code below which outputs all values in 1 div, but I need them to be separated so I can style/align them.

Any idea how I can do this?

I only just figured out how I can output the value, but I can find anywhere something about selecting and outputting the values separately.

Thank you.

```js
function selectedAfternoon(element) {
    var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("output-selected-option-afternoon").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<select id="Namiddag" name="Namiddag" data-name="Namiddag" class="js-basic-single" onChange="selectedAfternoon(this);">
  <option></option>
  <option id="13x19namiddag" value="Namiddag|13x19 cm|€12,50">13x19 cm, €12.50</option>
  <option id="20x30namiddag" value="Namiddag|20x30 cm|€22,50">20x30 cm, €22.50</option>
  <option id="30x45namiddag" value="Namiddag|30x45 cm|€32,50">30x45 cm, €32.50</option>
    <option class="disabled" value="disabled" disabled="disabled">Wil je meer stuks of formaten van deze foto? Vermeld dit dan in de winkelwagen., &nbsp;</option>
</select>

<div id="output-selected-option-afternoon"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a scenario where you select the first, second and third values as am really unable to understand what do you mean by *"I want to output the first, second and third value of a selected option"*.

Comment: See the comment of @VijayHardaha, that is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("output-selected-option-afternoon").innerHTML = "<div>" + text.split("|").join("</div><div>") + "</div>";`

Split by (|) then join with `</div><div>`

Comment: Okay so not exactly what I was looking for, but that’s on me because I didn’t specify this in my post. I want to give the last value in the div (so really the last div) a class, so I can calculate all selected options (I have 16 dropdowns) later on with JS. Do you have a solution for this too?

Comment: I thought it be wiser to create a new question for this so here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73481007/give-last-div-from-outputted-values-after-selection-from-dropdown-a-class